# What is an approximate font for the painting used in "The Treachery of Images"?

Tags: font-identification

What is a close approximation to the font used in René Magritte painting "[The Treachery of Images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)"?

[image: The Treachery of Images painting]

I tried the standard tools like WhatTheFont!, but they did a poor job with OCR on every letter except the **n**.

Comment: It's painted and not a font. That's the handwriting of Magritte..... but @Ilan seems to have found something close.

Comment: @Scott I do realize that it is a 100 year old painting, hence the wording of the question for a "close approximation". I was simply looking for something close to it and the standard tools failed.

Comment: *Ceci n'est pas une police* :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The picture you provided is very old, thus it is difficult to know if any modern font can perfectly match the text in the image.

You can use something somewhat similar, i.e.

[Pensle Bold Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ingrimayne/plain-pensle/bold-italic/) -

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I looked for the same font, and finally found this one, that looks a lot like the one in the image. What caught my eye was the handling of 'p' and 's'. The capital 'c' is different.
http://www.1001freefonts.com/parisienne.font
[image: image demonstrating parisienne font]

Answer (score 5):

LaTeX has a good French Cursive font for this (frcursive.sty)
[image]